# Image thumbnails blury on mobile search results

Tags: seo, wordpress

I am having an issue with an image appearing extremely blurry on google search results. The original image is not small and is not blurry yet it is hardly recognizable in the search. Please does anyone have any insight into this? Its from a WordPress site and using Imagify as a compression tool.

[image]

Comment: I've had problems of blurring when images are reduced.  Could you use an @media query to specify different images to be used at different resolutions?

Comment: Have you tried regenerating the thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an overcompressed, not ideal sized image.
Depending on your settings - either uncompress this image or upload an uncompressed image as post image/featured image.

Comment: The original image is 947px wide and is not compressed at all